# Configurar SSL en apache2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

Actualmente estoy trabajando con `Ubuntu 24.04` y estoy tratando de instalar apache2 y configurarlo para un `certificado SSL`.

Os comento lo que estoy haciendo, una vez instalado y funcionando me voy a `/etc/apache2/sites-available` y edito el archivo `default-ssl.conf` con mis datos apuntando a los certificados correctos.

Les adjunto el archivo de configuración tal cual estoy tratando de usar.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@factorycasas.es

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile      /home/usuario/Escritorio/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /home/usuario/Escritorio/server.key    
    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
    #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #    into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #    directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(?:cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Tengo que decir que estoy 100% seguro de que los archivos están en el lugar correcto y funcionan ya que también he probado a ponerlo así.

```
SSLCertificateFile      /home/usuario/Escritorio/server.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /home/usuario/Escritorio/server.priv
```

Estos son los nombres de archivos que tengo, he de decir que en `windows` no me dan ningún problema, el problema viene al colocarlos en `Ubuntu`.

Una vez editado el archivo lo guardo y ejecuto la siguiente orden:

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf
```

También he intentado hacerlo en un archivo de configuración aparte, el mismo código pero llamado `servidor-seguro.conf` y con el código:

```
sudo a2ensite servidor-seguro.conf
```

A la hora de reiniciar `apache`, usando el siguiente código:

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

Me arranca bien pero al intentar acceder a `https://localhost` no me funciona.

Espero que después de todo esto me puedan echar una mano para poder acceder a `https://localhost`

a la hora de acceder a https://localhost me sale esta pantalla

[image: https://localhost]

decir también que los certificados que estoy usando son los que me ha proporcionado la entidad a la que los he comprado (arsys.es)

mirando manuales he visto que me faltaba por poner este comando

```
a2enmod ssl
```

una vez introducido me sale que tengo que reiniciar apache2 con el siguiente comando:

```
systemctl restart apache
```

lo introduzco y ya no me deja arrancar apache2, me da el siguiente fallo:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
```

si pongo `systemctl status apache2.service`
Me arroja estas lineas que no entiendo muy bien.

```
ubuntu-huawei systemd[1]: Starting apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
ubuntu-huawei apachectl[25621]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 ubuntu-huawei systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ubuntu-huawei systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ubuntu-huawei systemd[1]: Failed to start apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
```

Mirando los error.log de apache2 me encuentro estas lineas:

```
[Tue Jan 16 22:55:44.432403 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25778:tid 126463166859136] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate 127.0.1.1:443:0 (with chain), check /home/usuario/Escritorio/ssl/server.crt
[Tue Jan 16 22:55:44.432441 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25778:tid 126463166859136] SSL Library Error: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Tue Jan 16 22:55:44.432447 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 25778:tid 126463166859136] SSL Library Error: error:0A080009:SSL routines::PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, llevo varios dias intentandolo y no salgo de los mismos errores siga el manual que siga.

Comment: es que el certificado que estas generando localmente no existe en los storage del sistema operativo

Comment: a mi me paso algo similar con docker

Comment: fue necesario, crear los certificados ssl en mi S.O con _mkcert_ para despues desplegarlos al servidor de desarrollo, da la casualidad que _mkcert_ instala automaticamente los certificados en el local storage y quedan disponibles para cuando navegues en el browser.

Comment: esto yo lo combine con dominios locales de desarrollo, algo como https://sub.tupapa.dock/

Comment: ahora decir que no te funciona no es suficiente ... que no ye funciona tienes que ser mas especifico, no arranca el apache, no funciona la url, que dice los log de apache???

Comment: de momento voy a votar para el cierre por que considero que te hace falta brindar mas infirmacion.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, espero me puedan echar una mano 
@Francisco Nuñez IA Lover

Answer (score 1):

Tras investigar mucho he encontrado que el fallo es que el archivo crt o pem (original de windows) tiene una linea en blanco tras -----END CERTIFICATE-----

tras borrar la linea, el servidor arranca correctamente y me muestra la pagina https://localhost

Gracias a todos los que se han tomado tiempo para ayudarme y leer mis parrafadas.